# Heuristic reason for Rademacher Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Loosely speaking [Rademacher Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem) states that Lipschitz functions are almost everywhere differentiable.

Is there a heuristic justification for this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by heuristic justification? an intuitive explanation?

Comment: @layabout yes :)